# Why does CORS work in some places, but not in others?

Tags: php, laravel, cors

In my Laravel app, I have set up a catch all route to handle CORS preflight requests.

```
Route::options('/{any}', 'v1\ApiController@handleCors')->where('any', '.*');
```

This goes to a function that does this:

```
return response()
            ->json($data, $this->statusCode)
            ->header('Accept', '*/*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://frontend.myapp.com')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
```

Now when, I call a route with an `OPTIONS` request, I get all the headers back. Then I ran the following command in Terminal:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: https://frontend.myapp.com" \
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization' \
"https://api.myapp.com/testingcors"
```

I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2019 15:29:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.10
Cache-Control: no-cache, private

Origin not allowed%
```

And when I let the actual frontend talk to the API, it will throw the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe CORS headers are generally applied to the app instance, not the response.

```php
// set the CORS headers in your app
header('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://frontend.myapp.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');

// return a response normally
return response()->json($data, $this->statusCode);
```

Comment: The general idea should be correct.  Try changing your headers to what I have updated the answer to above.  I had just copied your headers straight over for reference.